# Sorting in Moodle table on cohort name instead of cohortid

Tags: sorting, moodle

In Moodle table I want to sort column on name of cohort, but it's keeping sorting on cohortid. In end of url stays &tsort=cohortid.

My code in the function is beneath, what would be the necessary change?

```
    global $DB;
    $rs = array();
    $records = $DB->get_records_sql("SELECT c.id, c.name FROM {cohort} c
        LEFT JOIN {block_name_of_block} b ON b.cohortid = c.id
        WHERE b.cohortid = ?
        ORDER BY c.name ASC
        ", array($values->cohortid, $sort='c.name'));

    foreach ($records as $record) {
        $rs[] = $record->name;
    }
    return .. (=url)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you pass the parameter "tsort" having the value "cohortid", and it overrides the order defined in your query.

Try to identify where this parameter has been defined and either change its value into "name" or simply do not pass it.